# Cycling through an array modularly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got an ordered array of objects, myBros. I want each one to get its own  index in the array (which I'm storing as myPlace) and store the ID of the following one, with the last object storing the ID of the first.

The code below results in each object storing the ID of the last object, not the next one. On a positive note, the last object stores the ID of the first one.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have been more specific-this function lives in an object (a React component) which has some props, one of which is an id. getNextBroId returns a value based on the component's index.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: reworked the code in accordance with Daniel Beck's suggestion, still having the same problem.

```
for (let i = 0; i < myBros.length - 1; i++) {
    myBros[i].nextBroId = myBros[i + 1]._id;
}
myBros[myBros.length - 1].nextBroId = myBros[0]._id;
const myPlace = myBros.findIndex(p => p._id === id);
const getNextBroId = () => {
    return myBros[myPlace].nextBroId;
};
```

EDIT: I've posted the entire component here: [React-cycling through components in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161990/react-cycling-through-components-in-an-array) and am considering closing this question to avoid redundancy.

Comment: What is `this.props.id`?

Comment: `getNextBroId()` doesn't take any arguments, so it always returns the same thing.

Comment: I don't see how any of this is supposed to do something to every element of an array. Where do you loop over the array?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific-this function lives in an object (a React component) which has some props, one of which is an id. getNextBroId returns a value based on the component's index.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where boring old iteration is going to be a lot easier (and more performant) than the more exciting new techniques.

```js
var myBros = [
  {_id: "a"},
  {_id: "b"},
  {_id: "c"},
  {_id: "d"},
  {_id: "e"}
]

// step through all but last element in the array, link each one to the next
for (var i = 0; i < myBros.length - 1; i++) {
  myBros[i].nextBroId = myBros[i + 1]._id; 
}

// link the last one back to the first
myBros[myBros.length - 1].nextBroId = myBros[0]._id;

// and we're done
console.log(myBros);
```

(I'm not entirely sure why you would want to turn an array into a pseudo linked list, but I assume you have your reasons...)

Comment: The issue is that I am operating from within the objects in the array, not on the array level.

Comment: I see.  Hard to say without context but I suspect it'd still be easier to add these IDs wherever in your code you have the full array handy, instead of waiting until you're at the individual-component level.

Comment: (But, that said, have you confirmed that your `getNextBroId()` is actually returning the correct value?  I'm no React expert but from your description it sounds like that's likely the problem.)

Comment: It is returning the correct value and storing it. I've reworked the code a bit in accordance with your suggestion, but am still having the same problem-it skips between first and last.

Comment: OK.  Sorry, someone who knows more about React than I do may have to take it from here, I have a suspicion this is more about overwriting react state than the array manipulation itself...